# Ideas to create 'tables' able to be queried selecting only some fields?

Tags: indexeddb

I know indexeddb store 'objects' in every objstore. 
I'm using a cursor, with or without a key range.
Is it possible to retrieve only some 'fields'?

That is, something similar to "SELECT field1, field2", only some fields.

My main problem... I'm saving an image for every item.

```
object1 : field1, field2, .... image ... fieldn
object2 : field1, field2, .... image ... fieldn
...
objectn : field1, field2, .... image ... fieldn
```

I want to make an initial query to retrieve all 'fields' (or some fields) except the image.

My idea is to retrieve only the data I need.

If not... What can be the 'trick' to solve it? 
Create 'parallel' objectstores ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

## SOLUTION

I'm going to play with  objectstore1_a and objectstore1_b with separated fields information but saved with the same id. ....
However ... nobody thought that object-store-filter could be neccesary ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using two object stores.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to retrieve partial. All read/write to indexeddb is in full.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can write your own method to do this. Currently I'm working on it in my MostachoDB library for my thesis.

```
function getSpecificFields(o, fields) {
        var tmpo = {};
        for(var key in o) {
            if(o.hasOwnProperty(key) && (fields.indexOf(key) > -1 || fields == '*'))
                tmpo[key] = o[key];
        }
        return tmpo;
    };
```

This should do the trick if mixed with `cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

Compound index can be used for projection query such as:

```
objectStore.createIndex('proj_index', ['id', 'field1', 'field2'])
```

Then to query

```
// SELECT field1, field2 WHERE id = id1
var kr = IDBKeyRange.bound([id1], [id1, '\uffff], false, true);
objectStore.index('proj_index').get(kr).onsuccess = function(e) {
  var comp_key = e.target.result;
  callback({
     'field1': comp_key[1],
     'field2': comp_key[2]
  });
 }
```